# AWS EKS Worker Nodes Going "NotReady"

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm creating a new EKS Kubernetes Cluster on AWS.

When I deploy my workloads (migrating from an existing cluster) Kubelet stopps posting node status and all worker nodes become "NotReady" within a minute.

I was assuming that a misconfiguration within my cluster should not make the nodes crash - but apperently it does.

Can a misconfiguration within my cluster really make the AWS EKS Worker Nodes "NotReady"? Are there some rules of thumb under what circumstances this can happen? CPU Load to high? Pods in kube-system crashing?

Comment: As far I know the state happens when the kubelet pod is unable to call the API server (or vice versa?), so e. g. applying restrictive network policies to the kube-system namespace, sec. group or subnets can cause the node to be "not ready". Over-commiting memory can have bad effect too. Maybe you could deploy individual configurations step by step and see what may cause the state. Kubelet logs could definitely help to pinpoint the issue

Comment: You need to provide more information. You are using EKS, do you have any quotas? Could you describe node and provide output? Didn't you reach your $ balance?

Comment: @gusto2 "the state happens when the kubelet pod is unable to call the API server" - yes, this actually was the case! thank you! In the end looking carefully at the health status of EKS in the AWS console gave me the hint that the connection between worker and master node was broken due to some VPC misconfiguration.

Comment: Is your cluster having the right size of resources needed ? Try changing the nodes instance size.

Comment: I experienced this while trying to deploy worker nodes in a public subnet. From the EKS docs,  "If you plan to deploy nodes to a public subnet, the subnet must auto-assign IPv4 public addresses or IPv6 addresses". For me, the solution was to set 'map_public_ip_on_launch = true'  for my public subnet where the worker instances were being deployed.

Answer (score 3):

This is a community wiki answer based on the solution from comments and posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

As suggested by @gusto2 the problem was with the kubelet pod that was unable to call the API server. @stackoverflowjakob late confirmed that the connection between worker and master node was broken due to [VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/?vpc-blogs.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&vpc-blogs.sort-order=desc) misconfiguration and it was discovered by checking [AWS Console](https://aws.amazon.com/console/) -> EKS status.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the default PSP (pod security policy)? In my case, I added new eks.restricted psp, and new nodes will be NotReady status. My solution is to restore eks.privileged psp.

```
---
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodSecurityPolicy
metadata:
  name: eks.privileged
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/description: 'privileged allows full unrestricted access to
      pod features, as if the PodSecurityPolicy controller was not enabled.'
    seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/allowedProfileNames: '*'
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    eks.amazonaws.com/component: pod-security-policy
spec:
  privileged: true
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
  allowedCapabilities:
  - '*'
  volumes:
  - '*'
  hostNetwork: true
  hostPorts:
  - min: 0
    max: 65535
  hostIPC: true
  hostPID: true
  runAsUser:
    rule: 'RunAsAny'
  seLinux:
    rule: 'RunAsAny'
  supplementalGroups:
    rule: 'RunAsAny'
  fsGroup:
    rule: 'RunAsAny'
  readOnlyRootFilesystem: false

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: eks:podsecuritypolicy:privileged
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    eks.amazonaws.com/component: pod-security-policy
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - policy
  resourceNames:
  - eks.privileged
  resources:
  - podsecuritypolicies
  verbs:
  - use

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: eks:podsecuritypolicy:authenticated
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/description: 'Allow all authenticated users to create privileged pods.'
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    eks.amazonaws.com/component: pod-security-policy
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: eks:podsecuritypolicy:privileged
subjects:
  - kind: Group
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    name: system:authenticated
```

Answer (score -4):

You can try `kubectl describe node $BAD_NODE`  or ssh into node and try `sudo dmesg -T` and
try restating the kubelet on the node `/etc/init.d/kubelet restart`

Or

```
systemctl restart kubelet
```

Or delete node (drain first)

```
kubectl drain <node-name>
kubectl delete node <node-name>
```